# How can I write a sentence in a smaller font?

Tags: support, editing-help

I would like to make a sentence small in a post. Is this feature available on SE?

For example, I want to finish my question on Stack Overflow with:

> PS: I'm using Matlab R2012b

I would like to make it smaller than the rest of the text.

Comment: To your specific example: please don't. That's probably important information; why make it less visible?

Comment: Because it is not so important information related to precedent ...

Comment: If it is important, mention it in your question. If it is not important, then why mention it at all? ᴵ ᵃᵐ ᵗʸᵖᶦᶰᵍ ᵗʰᶦˢ ᵒᶰ ᵃᶰ ᶦᴾᵃᵈ ², ˢᵗᶦᶫᶫ ᶰᵒᵗ ᵘᵖᵈᵃᵗᵉᵈ ᵗᵒ ᵗʰᵉ ᶰᵉʷᵉˢᵗ ᵛᵉʳˢᶦᵒᶰ ᵒᶠ ᶦᴼˢ ᶠᵒʳ ᵛᵃʳᶦᵒᵘˢ ʳᵉᵃˢᵒᶰˢ⋅ ᴼᶰᵉ ᶦˢ ᴵ ˢᵉᵉᵐ ᵗᵒ ʰᵃᵛᵉ ᶠᵒʳᵍᵒᵗᵗᵉᶰ ᵐʸ ᴾᴵᴺ ᶜᵒᵈᵉ⋅

Comment: Whisper when you are typing the text out, just like WHEN YOU SHOUT WHILE TYPING IT GOES INTO ALL CAPS.

Comment: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: The corresponding [meta.se] request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag

Comment: Simply eliminate that last sentence and put a matlab tag on the question.  There is no need for `<sub>`

Comment: If the version of matlab you run is relevant to your question, don't make it smaller.  If it is not relevant then just leave it out entirely.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>Such a feature does not exist because it makes text unreadable.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

> Use multiple `<sup>text</sup>` to get a small text.
>    
>   `<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>Such a feature does not exist because it makes text unreadable.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>` 
>  
>  
>  (where I used `<sup>` you can use `<sub>` as well). If you are sensitive for html5 correctness make sure to limit its use as described by the [W3C doc](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-sub-and-sup-elements.html)

Comment: Does `<sub><sup>hello</sup></sub>` for a more balanced location work?  :)

Answer (score 38):

Just using one `<sub>` block or `<sup>` block will suffice.*

<sup>*:  Suffice as in "will do; you *really* don't need to make text much smaller than this.</sup>

Comment: Strange advice...more is better!

Comment: This is not semantically right according to the HTML5 rules.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: That may be so, but the point was that it *worked*, which it does a fine job of.

Comment: Well, but then again, some users *are* blind etc.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  Somehow I'm not as worried about that use case, even though a11y is always something web developers should keep towards the forefront of their minds.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Actually, for blind users, text that looks tiny is more readable than to us (via screen readers). Unless screen readers can whisper, which would be super cool.

Comment: @Camilo: That was not my point. My point was that the SUP element has [a specific meaning in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/single-page.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements). And it is *not* about less important information.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Would it be semantic of me to click the upvote button for your comment if it's [a link nested under ***three levels of tables and with `&nbsp;`s used for layout***](http://i.imgur.com/zXuWqRU.png)?

Comment: I know. I certainly didn't design that markup...

Answer (score 15):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>Don't.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 8):

## You <sub><sup>can <sub><sup>fake <sub><sup>it</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

## <sub><sup>But</sup></sub> <sub><sup><sub><sup>it's not</sup></sub></sup></sub> really <sub><sup><sub><sup>readable</sup></sub></sup></sub>

## <sub><sup><sub><sup>and I would</sup></sub></sup></sub> go <sub><sup>as <sub><sup><sub><sup>far</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub> <sub><sup><sub><sup>as to call it</sup></sub> a</sup></sub> bad <sub><sup>practice</sup></sub>.

Comment: ʸᵒᵘ ᶜᵃᶰ ᵈᵒ ᶦᵗ ᶦᶰ ᶜᵒᵐᵐᵉᶰᵗˢ ᵗᵒᵒ ﹕⁻⁾

Comment: @JonasCz fun fact: your comment rendered *empty* on the email reminder StackOverflow sent me.