# Visited links don't disappear with the rest of the spoiler block

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spoilers

When you hover out of a spoiler block, the text disappears.

> This is a spoiler.

However, it appears that the styling of visited links prevents them from disappearing with the rest of the block.

[image: Example]
<sub>From [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295141/how-can-i-write-a-sentence-in-a-smaller-font/295142#295142) (although the post has changed, it still contains a link).</sub>

You can also test it here:

> A [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295514/visited-links-dont-disappear-with-the-rest-of-the-spoiler-block) that you have probably visited.

---

As a side note, links that you haven't visited are still visible in the spoiler block as an underline, which can be seen here:

[image: Unvisited link]

Test:

> A [link](http://asdfxyz123.com) that you probably haven't visited.

Safari 8.0.6 on OS X 10.10.3, if relevant to this particular issue.

Comment: Wait… OS X *what*‽ You mean 10.10.3, right?

Comment: @bjb568 [I knew I mixed up those version numbers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295514/2).

Comment: Also reported [on Puzzling Meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/should-we-consider-adding-links-in-spoiler-tags/).

Comment: Also, the fading effect does not work on links, they disappear and appear instantly while the text fades.

Comment: And also reported on MSE: [Visited links within spoilers are not hidden anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256941/visited-links-within-spoilers-are-not-hidden-anymore)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Nice find; I didn't think to search Meta.SE because I assumed it was unique to recent design changes on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Confirmed. This also occurs on windows, using Firefox.

Comment: And on windows using Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spoiler CSS rules didn't consider visited links, so those got rendered fully.

This has been fixed and will be with you in the next build.